# How to use ajax post method with golang server side endpoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, go

I need some help to apply my endpoint that's working in Postman to work with client side
using ajax I tried some of the online snippet codes but it seems I have an issue in my own code that needs to be reviewed.

1. Server Side (Golang Code)

```
type DirectMessage struct {
    FullName   string `json:"fullName"`
    Email      string `json:"email"`
    Message    string `json:"message"`
    ID         int     `json:"id"`
}

func AddNewDM(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db := ConnectDB()
    defer db.Close()
    dm := DirectMessage {}
    Decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    err := Decoder.Decode(&dm)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    db.Create(DirectMessage {FullName: dm.FullName, ID: dm.ID, Email: dm.Email, Message:dm.Message})
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "New DM created")
}
func httpRequests() {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/api/new_dm/{id}/{fullName}/{email}/{message}", AddNewDM).Methods("POST")
    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", router)
}
func main() {
    db := ConnectDB()
    db.AutoMigrate(&DirectMessage{})
    defer db.Close()
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html"))
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./templates"))
    http.Handle("/templates/", http.StripPrefix("/templates/", fs))
    httpRequests()
}
```

Form HTML - JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <header>
            <title> Add New User </title>
        </header>
         <body>
            <form>
                <label for="fullName">FullName:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="FullName" name="FullName"><br>
                <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>
                <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
                <input type="message" id="message" name="message"><br>
                <button id = "submit_form" class="form_button" type="submit">Send It!</button>
            </form>
        <body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: With a form like that, the browser will not send JSON to your endpoint. Try the [`ParseForm`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseForm) method, then check the content of `r.PostForm`. Edit: and this HTML form will also probably send an GET request, not a POST request.

Comment: Add a `method="post"` to your `<form>` tag in HTML, then use the ParseForm method and then check the content of `r.PostForm`